# How to receive input from 2 files on an executable

Tags: command-line, executable, input

Basically, I want to receive input from 2 different files whem I'm calling an executable on terminal

Like:

```
./a.out < file1.pgm file2.pgm
```

I want to read both the files input on my code, one after another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the question, where file1.pgm and file2.pgm are files whose contents you want sent to a.out as input:

```
cat file1.pgm file2.pgm | ./a.out
```

If file1.pgm and file2.pgm are executables that *produce* output for a.out:

```
(file1.pgm; file2.pgm) | ./a.out
```

Comment: This will send the output of the two `.pgm` executables in sequence.  If they're just text files for input, you can use `(cat file1.pgm file2.pgm) | /path/to/executable` instead.

Comment: Does not work for me. It says "file1.pgm: command no found. file2.pgm: command no found" and then runs the program.

Comment: DopeGhoti solution works, thanks!
If you want, write that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ahh, I completely misunderstood -- thanks, DopeGhoti! Even simpler: `cat file1.pgm file2.pgm | ./a.out`

Comment: Go ahead and give @JeffSchaller the answer credit; my comment was a minor tweak to a mostly correct answer after all.

Comment: *gasp*. `cat` actually being used for concatenation. I feel blessed to have witnessed such an event :-)

Comment: @Patrick I can only hope that I've removed one of my early years' UUOC awards :)